# rails not picking style in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class="field hash-tag col-md-12">
  <%= form.label :hash_tags, '#Hashtags' %> 
    <span class="samples">(e.g #smile #food #life)
    </span>
  <%= form.text_area :hash_tags, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>


.samples{
 color: #4cae4c;
}


 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min.css
 *= require font-awesome.min.css
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require jquery-ui/accordion
```

In the view file I have given a 'samples' class to span and in stylesheet file I am applying color to that span. It's working in localhost but not working in production.when i inspect with ctrl+shift+i it shows all styles except that samples class style.

Comment: Where did you defined your `samples` css?

Comment: in my topics.scss file

Comment: Is it under `assets/stylesheets`? Did you add it to `application.css` file?

Comment: it's under assets/stylesheets....no i did'nt add it to application.css file

Comment: Could you please add `application.css` code to the question?

Comment: What do you use for deployment? Heroku?

Comment: i added the application.css code in question..   
i use bitbucket for deployment

Comment: Try to move `require_tree .` to the last line from the first one.

Comment: btw, you're duplicating bootstrap and font-awesome. It shouldn't be the cause of your issue, but in any case you don't need these css twice. Remove min versions

Comment: moving require_tree from top to last works for me

Comment: Happy to help you! I posted the answer, accept it please, to not leave the question unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll convert my comments to the answer, if you don't mind.

Order of requiring in manifest file really matters, your css rules are applied one by one, and the latest one has precedence over the first one. That's why sometimes you have to remove `require tree .` at all and require all files manually in needed order.

Looks like your  `samples` is overwritten somewhere. Or maybe duplicating of font-awesome and bootstrap leads to the issue. Remove duplicates and move `require tree` to the last line:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require font-awesome
*= require jquery-ui/accordion
*= require_tree .
```